# Not sure how to declare

Tags: c++, declaration

Here's the compiler error

```
kdtilemapper.cpp:14: error: 'tiles' was not declared in this scope
kdtilemapper.cpp:17: error: 'const class KDTileMapper' has no member named 'tiles'
```

here is the code in question.

```
KDTileMapper::KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs):TileMapper(rhs,tiles)
{
source = rhs.source;
tiles = rhs.tiles;
}
```

here is the  class

```
class KDTileMapper : public TileMapper
{
public:
    KDTileMapper( const SourceImage & si,const vector<TileImage> & tiles);
    ~KDTileMapper();
    KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs & tiles);
    KDTileMapper const & operator=(KDTileMapper const & rhs);
    int map_tiles(MosaicCanvas & mosaicOut) const;
private:
    KDTree<TileImage>* tileMapKDT;
```

Comment: You should provide the class declaration for us to help better.

Comment: @Brain - If this is the full declaration of class `KDTileMapper`, then it has no member variable named `tiles` as the compiler is complaining about. `KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs & tiles);` ??????

Answer (score 2):

```
KDTileMapper::KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs):TileMapper(rhs,tiles)
```

You are passing the arguments `rhs, tiles` to the base class `TileMapper` constructor. But the compiler doesn't know what the identifier `tiles` is.

Probably you meant -

```
KDTileMapper::KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs):TileMapper(rhs,rhs.tiles) 
                                                                 // ^^^ newly added.
```

But the modification is not at all required if you just make the `TileMapper` constructor receive just one const argument of type `KDTileMapper` by reference because `tiles` is already part of the `rhs` object ( if it is actually a member variable. But the second error message says it isn't ).

Answer (score 0):

You should put private TILES_TYPE tiles in KDTileMapper class definition or TILES_TYPE tiles in constructor